# In the Almighty Johnsons, is Gaia 21?

Tags: the-almighty-johnsons

The obvious question from *The Almighty Johnsons*, after watching the first season, is whether Gaia could potentially be Frigg?  If she has had her 21st birthday, that rules it out under what is currently known of the god-rules.  I vaguely remember some references to her birthday in one of the earlier episodes, but I can't remember which episode nor the context.  So is Gaia 21 yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Season 2, episode 9:

> Gaia is revealed as being under 21 and currently going through the Goddess transition.

Answer (score 3):

She has her 22nd birthday in episode 9 of the first season, ["Hunting Reindeer on Slippery Rocks"](http://thealmightyjohnsons.co.nz/episodes/series-1/episode-9/), so that most likely rules her out - or she just hasn't let anything on yet.

More significantly, in [episode 10](http://thealmightyjohnsons.co.nz/episodes/series-1/episode-10/),

> Axl and Gaia have sex

and nothing godly happens, so if the theory about them recognising each other is right, then it can't be her.

Comment: I had just watched that episode.  I must have missed them talking about her age in it.  As to the spoiler, I was suspecting it wouldn't work if one was under 21.

Comment: @dlanod perhaps so.  Her age was mentioned early in the episode (in the first mention of the party, I believe).  Unfortunately I don't have the DVDs any more and the episode's too old to be available online, so I can't add a transcript.

Comment: Season 2, Episode 3 just referred to her being too old as well.

Comment: Season 2, Episode 9 obviously changes this all...  Don't take the unaccept personally - I left the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

So far we have only seen the god rules and initiation applied to the male gods. We don't know yet how a goddess is initiated, or if the same god rules apply to the females. We know that a goddess can leave a body and take up residence in another. This host theory may explain how Gaia could be a goddess and be of Maori descent. Interestingly, in a recent episode where Axl discovers his feminine side, Gaia appears to display masculine traits.

Also, another thought. Does anybody think that the mother, Freyja, is really Loki? It would explain a few things that are currently happening. The mother, Agnetha, appears to be gathering/searching for Niflheim Gods. Have they been in a scene together? Not that this rules out Loki still being the mother, as Loki can project images.

Otherwise, perhaps Loki could have an alliance with Freyja.

Comment: The second part is probably deserving of its own question, but the two of them have definitely been in a scene together - specifically the Eva/Axl scene where they attempt to break off the wedding and the "catch" is revealed.  They were definitely in an alliance at the end of Season 1, as Freyja visited Loki when finding out about Eva and conspired with him in the translation of the runic contract so that the "catch" went undiscovered.

Comment: Quite right. I forgot that they have been in a scene together. I still hold firm to my belief that loki and Freyja are in an alliance despite the most recent episode where loki attempted to kill her after discovering she was the killer of hel (hel is now where she belongs anyway according to myth). This may all be part of a master plan leading to Ragnarok. Loki after all is the great deciever, trickster.

Comment: I wouldn't put it past Loki to give the ok to kill his own daughter. The human form, Colin, may have held reservations but it is the God in their mortal bodies that rules them (think of how eva struggled with the goddess Hel). As for frejya she may have easily turned into a tree elsewhere in the forest.

Answer (score 0):

I think its pretty simple... Gaia is 22 and Its my opinion that she is Frigg... she already may have gone through rites when she turned 21 remember she kept insisting that her family was weird you may want to chalk that to her Gay father but the wise god said Frigg finds Odin, well she did on his birthday only Mr. Axl wasn't ready and when he admits his feelings she gives him a chance but Mr. Axl falls short again, then she leaves until he can prove his manhood by rescuing her from her obvious tool of a bf... well that's my take. Ultimately its the writer of the story that determines this she/ he could spin it which ever way they like! :)